# IE stops executing JavaScript before calling handler using clientscript.registerstartup

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", "HideProgress
();window.location.href='DownloadFile.ashx';", true);
Handler file:
public class DownloadFile : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        if (context.Session["fileContent"] != null && context.Session["filename"] != null)
        {
            //Download the excel file
            System.IO.StringWriter fileContent = (System.IO.StringWriter)context.Session["fileContent"];
            string filename = context.Session["filename"].ToString();
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
            context.Response.Write(fileContent.ToString());
            context.Response.Flush();
        }

}
```

Textbox with calender control does showing calender image in IE after file download.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have DOCTYPE declared

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

along with user agent indicator to tell IE to use the latest rendering engine available

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Where should i include this?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> should be the very first statement in your file, <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> should be included immediately after <head> begins

Comment: I am skeptical about this, but most IE related issues [JS and CSS] get resolved using this, hope it helps you too!